# How to load host application with all it's remotes in NX Monorepo?

Tags: angular, monorepo, webpack-module-federation, nomachine-nx, nx-monorepo

To start host with remotes I use --devRemotes option. For example:
`nx serve my-console --devRemotes=my-assets,my-dashboard`

Is there a way to serve start my-console with all of it's remotes in "dev" mode?
I tried to search NX documentation and SO, but didn't found an answer.

Thank you!.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure this in your host's project.json, inside the "serve" object:
[image]